# OpenCV C++ detect line and coordinates and move it to the another image

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

We're trying to make a game called *PaperSoccer* using C++ and [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/).

The original board looks like this: [original board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDVWv.jpg)

And picture with one move looks like this: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhWTG.jpg)

We're using perspective transform to remove the perspective in the second picture and we're able to find coordinates of points (dots). [Source code](https://github.com/adrtysz/Pilkarzyki/blob/master/Program/src/Perspective.cpp)

We want to detect the place where the move was made and move it to the original board.

We tried to use `absdiff(img1,img2,result)` to find the difference between the board and the photo, and then use

```
int DetectLines(Mat src, const char* sourceName, const char* destName){

Mat dst, cdst;
Mat zapisz;
zapisz = imread("plansza3.jpg",0);

Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);
cvtColor(dst, cdst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);


vector<Vec4i> lines;

HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 20, 10, 5);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line(zapisz, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 2);
}

imshow(destName, zapisz);

return 0;
}
```

to find the line and draw it on the board, but it's not working.

The most important is the fact that we need coordinates of the line (move) for the logic of the game, ie two points. We do not necessarily have to transfer it to the original board, but we must in some way convey that the center point in the picture corresponds to the center point on the original board etc.

Comment: Can you expand on the results you already have? You mention the difference is not working...what is the issue? Also, are you supposed to find only one line, or there can be multiple lines (moves)? How about some color-based processing, since the move line seems to be red?

Comment: we tried to use ROI(region of intrest) and we can easily find the move. But we have a problem with getting that move onto a new .jpg that will user see while playing. The problem is that while using ROI we are cutting photo and we don't know how make it in right place at the end.

Comment: Since you can reliably detect the points in the 2 images, why not perform an affine/perspective transform to match them, and then extract the line? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: if you remember where you've set the roi you can easily transform the local coordinates back the original image. If your roi is at place (roix,roiy) with size (roiwidth, roiheight), a point (x,y) in the roi image is at point (x+roix, y+roiy) in the original image.

Comment: @Micka thank you!!